# Find a Mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in an all-pay auction

Tags: game-theory

This is an all-pay auction (Highest bidder wins the object, all players pay what they bid, player 1 wins all ties): Player 1 has $300$ dollars, Player 2 has $500$ dollars, the object being auctioned is $100$ dollar bill. The two players only care about the amount of cash they carry at the time the auction ends.

Player 1 has utility $u_1 (x) = x^{1/2}$, Player 2 has utility $u_2 (x) = ln (x)$ for $x$ dollars. Player 1 bids between $[0,300]$, player 2 bids between $[0,500]$.

Find a **mixed-strategy** Nash equilibrium.

I know that I'm supposed to eliminate all strictly dominated strategies first, and I think Player 2 has $(300,500]$ as strictly dominated strategy. But I'm stuck to find the mixed strategy Nash equilibrium. Could someone help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: You can restrict it tighter:  Since either player can end up with his starting money by bidding zero, and any bit beyond 100 inevitably ends up with less than his starting money,all strategies involving bids past 100 are strictly dominated.  The significance of the starting amounts comes into play only because they affect the utility of any given gain or loss.

Comment: Here are the utility functions I derived: $u_1(b_1,b_2)$=
\begin{cases}
(400-b_1)^{1/2},  & \text{if $b_1 \ge b_2$} \\
(300-b_1)^{1/2}, & \text{if $b_1 \lt b_2$}
\end{cases}

$u_2(b_1,b_2)$=
\begin{cases}
ln(600-b_2),  & \text{if $b_2 \gt b_1$} \\
ln(500-b_2), & \text{if $b_2 \le b_1$}
\end{cases}

Comment: @MarkFischler To find the mixed strategy, suppose bidder 2 bids $b_2 \in [0,100]$, his expected payoff would be: $U_2 = P(b_2)*ln(600-b_2)+(1-P(b_2))*ln(500-b_2)=0$, where $P(b_2)$ is the probability distribution function of bidder 1 bidding less than bidder 2. But $P(b_2)$ is always less than $0$ and not in $[0,1]$, so there's no mixed strategy? Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Not quite:  What you are calling $P(b_2)$ most would call $F_1(b_2)$ because it is a *cumulative* distribution function:  $F_1(b_2) = P(b_1 \leq b_2$ with $b_1$ a random variate distributed according to player $1$'s strategy $P_1(x)$.  Thus what you are calling $P(b_2)$ is always in $[0,1]$.